# Problem with bluetooth ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I can't connect with my Nokia phone via Bluetooth. It's already added to devices..I can't browse it, nor send files. On ubuntu before, there wasn't problem. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Simply download Blueman from the Ubuntu Software Manager. Once Blueman installed right-click your device within Blueman and **trust it**. Will work great!

Answer (score 1):

You can send/receive after check Receives files in personal sharing preferences
but for browsing I dunno, I can't browse too.

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work..

Comment: Browsing the Android device from your Ubuntu is still not working. You may want to opt in this Launchpad bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/987986

Answer (score 1):

For me, I frequently use `blueman` (the Bluetooth Manager), and yes you can install it from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Wait for the installation to finish, and you can use the software as you like. As long as I'm using the software, I have no problems with receiving from the Bluetooth file transfer but yes, I did have problems if I want to transfer files from PC to my mobile phone.