# Bluetooth detected on 12.04LTS but cannot connect

Tags: bluetooth, android

I'm using a IOGear GBU311 on my desktop with 12.04LTS (I'm on kubuntu). I see the device in the Bluetooth conf. manager.

My computer can detect my phone.

On my phone (LG P930 with Android 2.3.5) I can detect my computer, get paired with it but it refuses to connect.

Someone has an idea about how to fix this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148679/problem-with-bluetooth-ubuntu-12-04) out. It is more generic but the solution there (installing blueman through `sudo apt-get install blueman` ) should also fix your problem.