# Can't send file to smartphone via bluetooth in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, phone

I'm a new Lubuntu user (never used any Linux OS before).

File Manager --> Preferences --> Bluetooth Manager

I can't seem to send a file to my smartphone. I click the bluetooth icon on the task bar, a window comes up showing my smartphone.

Clicked "Pair" to pair my laptop and smartphone. 
Once paired, the Send File button is activated, meaning I can already send a file. So I choose a 36MB .mp4 file, then send, then:

Request timeout
Error occurred while sending file video.mp4

First I thought it was because I'm using a custom ROM on my smartphone. But I switched to Windows 7 and was able to send the same file with no problem whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your customized device may need to allow your Lubuntu the appropriate profile for data transfer.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Ubuntu and its derivatives (like Lubuntu) have a [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148679/problem-with-bluetooth-ubuntu-12-04) on the bluetooth stack. On the same link it suggests using blueman (`sudo apt-get install blueman`) for all your bluetooth needs.
I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Bluetooth was very buggy.

Comment: I have installed already blueman, can receive and browse files of my smartphone from my ubuntu 12.04 LTS but, still not able to send files to it.

Comment: I don't really know whether the new version of Ubuntu fixes it... Now I'm using Windows :) @unmultimedio

Comment: Lubuntu 15.10 already includes blueman.   However, go to bluetooth setup/local services and check off accept files from trusted sources.  This makes life super easy.  I will copy this comment and answer this question

Comment: Maybe, but both the question and my answer are older than 14.04. The OP was using 12.04 in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.Make sure you have installed " Personal file sharing" and Blueman through ubuntu software center.Go to your phone > paired devices > new paired devices >Bluetooth devices .Now your phone will ask for a password, enter your password(any 4 digit number eg.1234). Then you can see a  window pops up on your computer screen. Enter the same number on computer. Now come back to your phone again to paired devices,choose "set as authorised "! Done it ! Now send your files from computer to phone,it will come smoothly !

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 15.10 already includes blueman.   However, go to bluetooth setup/local services and check off accept files from trusted sources.  This makes life super easy.  I will copy this comment and answer this question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you.
Here is what i did to solve it:

1) Open the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install blueman`

2) Open bluetooth manager (preferences -> bluetooth manager) and from its menu pair and trust your mobile device. (remeber to press 'pair' on the notification on your android device and 'confirm' on the pop up window on lubuntu.

3) In the terminal type `sudo blueman-sendto` (apparently blueman needs sudo to transfer the file otherwise it fails). A window will appear where you can navigate to your files, select the file you want to send, then select the paired device you want to send the file and press OK.

4) On your mobile device a message will appear asking if you accept the file, press accept and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The program that fixed my problem is called **[Blueman](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bluetooth/Blueman/)**. With Blueman you are able to accept those files sent by the phone.

You are also able to manage your connected devices.

When you start the application click on the button with the name "Setup" on it.

Select Audio Source and click next and you're done:

[image]